# Pushing: Repository not found. GitLab

Tags: git, version-control, repository, gitlab

When I run

```
git push -u origin master
```

I get the following:

```
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/user/project_name.git/'
```

However, I have an origin already set to my local repo.

I tried to delete and reset the origin but it does not work.
I am new to git; not really familiar with SHH keys and stuff.

Comment: The slash at the end of `'https://gitlab.com/user/project_name.git/'` looks suspicious. Could you add the output of `git remote -v` command?